# Efficient way of converting large adjacency matrices to edge lists in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I have **large sparse adjacency matrices** with around **1M nodes**, which I am processing with **MATLAB**. I want to convert these matrices into **network edge lists** as efficiently as possible. As an example adjacency matrix to illustrate this:

```
adj =
     1     0     1     0
     0     0     1     1
     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0
```

And the output I call an *network edge list* here is:

```
>> adj2edgeList_Alex(adj)
ans =
     0     0
     0     2
     1     2
     1     3
     2     2
     3     1
```

This code which I have to do it stalls for time.

```
function edge_list = adj2edgeList_Alex(graph)

edge_num = length(logical(graph > 0));
edge_list = zeros(edge_num,2);
row_ind = 1;
for ii=1:size(graph,2)
    ind_temp = find(graph(ii,:)==1);
    if(isempty(ind_temp) == 0)
        ind_temp = ind_temp - 1;
        edges_iter = length(ind_temp);   
        node_num = ii - 1;
        edge_list(row_ind:row_ind+edges_iter-1,:) = ...
            [(node_num)*ones(1,edges_iter);ind_temp]';
            row_ind = row_ind + edges_iter;
    end
end
```

Is there a modification to speed this up? Another function or toolbox that can perform better?

Comment: Have you profiled your code at all?  Use the profiler to see where it's acting slowly.  That will help give you clues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `find()`:

```
[r,c] = find(adj)
edges = [r,c];
```

Note that MATLAB indexes from 1 not 0, but you can rebase by simply `edges-1`.